# Text display in the bottom of emoji

Tags: android, android-layout

I display emoji in `EditText` using spannable, but the problem is that the text appears in the bottom of the emoji picture, not in the middle of it (see picture).

So, how to make it display in the middle?

[image]

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_tInput"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:maxLength="2000"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/black_cursor"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set gravity center for your `TextView`

```
android:gravity="center"
```

or

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

Comment: its not help ,this happ when there is text and emoji together in the EditText if one of them its work fine

Comment: OK share ur layout xml. Problem is there only

Comment: i add the EditText to the question

Comment: @steevoo did you tried the android:gravity="center_vertical" on your EditText ?

Comment: yeh its not help give same result and i also tried with TextView and also same result